# Book: troubleshooter born into a desolate future world

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi, space-exploration

I think the book or series is from the late 70s early 80s.  It's based in the future; the character was born in a desolate world and grew up with an almost animalistic survivability. It was not by L.E. Modesitt.  I want to say it had something to do with a binary sun.

The main character was like a troubleshooter.  The book may have actually been published late 50s or early 60s. The action was pulp fiction-ish.

Comment: That's not much to go on.  There are a lot of stories like this.  You might want to look at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question to help jog your memory about what else you might remember that would be helpful.

Comment: The main character was like a trouble shooter the book ma have actually been published late 50s. Early 60s. The action was pulp fiction-ish

Answer (score 2):

The *second* idea I had (after [The Forever Hero](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/185162.The_Forever_Hero)) was [Dumarest Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dumarest_saga), written by [E.C. Tubb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Charles_Tubb). The first (Winds of Gath) was published in 1969 with 30+ published over the next 15 years.

As mentioned in the comments though, there is really not a lot of detail in the question and the general shape matches a lot of books.

Comment: Meant on a desolate world where he was "uplifted" and educated

Answer (score -1):

Might be Harry Harrison 's *Deathworld* series. There's a good Wikipedia page (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathworld)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should add details from the story synopsis that match the points in the question.  Please read [answer].